# Hi I found a teapot and need help

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, transcription

[image]

I found a teapot with a maker's mark I'm trying to learn more and find out whose it is. Unfortunately I know nothing about these kind of things, I just thought was cool when I bought it, but would like to know more. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this says "葉成蔭制", but I'm not extremely confident about the first character.

Comment: @dROOOze, “葉” is better than my initial guess “華” 